# VS 2010 macro - select from here to there

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, macros

I'm writing a macro to let me replace the spaces in a string in my code file with underscores.  I've gotten as far as finding the beginning and end of the string as instances of `VirtualPoint`.  Now I'm trying to select from the first `VirtualPoint` to the second.  And I can't figure it out.

I know the `VirtualPoint`s are correct, because I'm using MessageBox.Show to tell me their values when I run the macro.  I just don't know the correct command to set the `TextSelection` from the first to the second.  I've tried this:

```
selection.MoveToPoint(firstVirtualPoint)
selection.MoveToPoint(secondVirtualPoint, True)
```

This seems like it ought to work, but it doesn't.  The cursor just moves to the end of the line (as far as I can tell).

Does anybody know the correct command for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As these things tend to go, after I give up, suddenly it hits me.  Perhaps this will help someone else, though.

A fuller sample of the code is this:

```
Dim selection As TextSelection = 
    CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection, TextSelection)
selection.StartOfLine()

selection.FindText("some string at start")
Dim pointAfterStart = selection.BottomPoint

selection.FindText("some string at end")
Dim pointBeforeEnd = selection.TopPoint

selection.MoveToPoint(pointAfterIt)
selection.MoveToPoint(pointBeforeLambda, True)
```

The idea is to find the initial text, then the ending text, and then select everything in between.  What I found in the debugger was that the values in pointAfterStart and pointBeforeEnd were *changing*.  Perhaps deceived by the name (since `System.Drawing.Point` is a struct), I wasn't realizing they were references that pointed to the *current* selection position.

I solved it this way:

```
selection.FindText("It ")
Dim pointAfterIt = selection.BottomPoint.CreateEditPoint

selection.FindText(" = () =>")
Dim pointBeforeLambda = selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint
```

This made copies of the selection points, so that they didn't change when the selection moved later.